# tun/tap interface understanding

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am currently exploring different networking interfaces  and came across tun/tap. I got confused about one part which was creating sockets.

Can we create regular sockets with well know ports on the ip address assigned to tun/tap interface?

Is it possible to create sockets for both tun and tap interfaces?

I apologies if it is too basic to ask it here. (I could not find enough online doc on this subject.)

P.S. I think as it is a networking interface, it should be possible.

Comment: After your tun/tap interface is up and running, there's nothing special about it. Of course you can create sockets and `bind` them to the interfaces's ip address (and available ports. Make sure you're root if you want ports below 1024).

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question. So, can I create sockets on either tun or tap. Cause one is over ethernet packets and other is over ip packets.

Comment: They *both* are network interfaces like any others, as far as sockets are concerned. Their underlying "devices" are different, and you'll see that difference if you want to *bridge* another ethernet network to them, for example. *No difference* with sockets and `bind`.

Comment: Hey, sorry for adding more questions about the stuff in the same thread. But I think questions are kind of related. If I create a tun-tap interface and assign an ip address to it then can anyone open sockets on it? My understanding is the interface itself can be guarded by uid and gid. So, when sockets are created on the ip are those things checked or communication fails silently?

Comment: Interfaces are not guarded by uid and gid. There are privileged ports (1-1024), but apart from that, anyone can create sockets. (You can filter by uid/gid of process in iptables to prevent packets from being sent, but it doesn't prevent socket creation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not? It is not different with any other network interfaces from the socket's point of view.

You just need to send the packets like what you do for other network interfaces. The packets you send via tun/tap interface will be read by the process (normally a hypervisor or some VPN daemon) from /dev/net/tun device automatically. These processes will further process the packets, for example, passing them to your guest.

So, unless you are programming hypervisor or some VPN daemon, you don't even notice the difference...